# the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document VS 2010 and VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012, symbols

I have tried going to Debug>Windows>Module .... loaded Symbols etc but doe not fix the issue
Also cleaned solution, restarted and does work
Created new projects both in VS 2010 and VS 2012 but both have same issue when trying to attach to a processes

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show any more information? From what you have given it will be difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: @nguthrie this was a Dynamics CRM application and I was trying to debug a Plugin. VS was not picking it up as my Plugin's mode was set to Sandbox and in sandbox mode you can not debug even if you drop pdb file. So by changing mode from sandbox to none fixed my issue and I was able to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. I had to drop pdb file in the bin directory of solution I was trying to debug i.e. myurl/abc.aspx

Also had to change Isolation Mode from sandbox to None and now all working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with the help of my friend Arnaldo Ono I found the solution, you need to load Load All Symbols in Visual Studio> Debug> Options> Debugging> Symbols> Load All Symbols.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you need to know where the symbol files are located :-)